# Как вывести в title элемент ифноблока?

Tags: битрикс

На данный момент вывожу title так

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?> | <?=$arSite['SITE_NAME']?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но это немного не соответствует пагинации. Т.е Статьи это инфоблока, а косметология это раздел внутри этого инфоблока, как вывести 'Косметология' в тайтл?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Либо в настройках компонента указать соответствующую опцию, либо в шаблоне добавить component_epilog.php файл и там добавить

```
<?php
$APPLICATION->SetTitle($arResult['NAME']);
```

Answer (score 0):

В настройках компонента можно `"установить заголовок окна браузера из свойства раздела"` (или элемента).

**Еще можно** разработать свою логику и в `component_epilog.php` шаблона компонента выводить через `$APPLICATION->SetTitle( $myTitle );`

**Но скорее всего вам подойдет это:**
Для каждого инфоблока, его разделов и элементов можно настроить "формулу" в закладке "SEO" и генерировать автоматом title, alt, keywords, description .. (для страницы, для картинок, для ссылок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]